# Applications flicker when I click the mouse

Tags: windows-7, mouse, malware

The best way I can show this is with games - which are entirely unplayable.
Here is a video of what is happening:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rqb5qPencVE

Notice that it happens every time I click.

I have another video of it happening with Half Life and Dark Souls (but its not as clear that it happens on click in that one)
This happens with every application, its just far more visual with fullscreen applications.

This never happened before I started having issues with some extensions not installing in chrome (fixed that...), and I reached out to a friend from university who sent me an exe that he pulled from a forum on google that installed a shit-ton of adware into my system.

So, after I realized what was happening, I rebooted into Ubuntu and cleared my %temp% and deleted a few suspicious folders from c:\programdata.
I then rebooted into safe mode, uninstalled everything that I didn't put there and that wasn't supposed to be there as a dependency, CCleaned the system, and ran two virus scans and removed everything that came up. The system is fine adware-wise now, no programs that I can find in the program files/programdata/%temp% or anywhere else. (Or through the control panel for that matter)

I checked my graphics drivers, and I tried it on an external (in the video) and on my main monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Here The
Instructions:

1. Click Start .
2. In the Start Search textbox type Services.msc If prompted by the UAC, provide a password or confirmation. Click Continue .
3. Scroll down until you locate the entry that is labeled Desktop Window Manager Session Manager.
4. Right-Click on this service. Select Stop from the context menu.
5. Right Click once again on the entry. Select Properties from the context menu.
6. Go to the “General Tab ” to change the start up type to Disabled. Click OK .